# Button sticking to form when below textarea

Tags: html, css, forms, media-queries, contact-form

I'm trying to center a button at the bottom of a form I'm making. I have this media query: @media screen and (min-width: 30em), which takes the columns from 100% to 50% above the query. Similarly, the button goes from width: 100%, to width: auto.

It should look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lacrx/ezj2us8x/2/), but with the submit button at the bottom

However, when I put the button on the bottom, it appears to stick to the right column. It looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lacrx/vtk3oe95/) for some reason.

Here's my HTML

```
    <form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer.php">
        <div class="column">
            <label for="name">name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
            <label for="email">email address</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <label for="message">message</label>
            <textarea id="message" required></textarea>
        </div>

        <button id="bottom-button" type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
```

Here's my CSS

```
button {
    background: #e85657;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0.5em;
    font-family:"Lato", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-left: 1.05em;
    padding-right: 1.05em;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
button:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #e85657;
}
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
#form-messages {
    font-family:"Lato", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #553445;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
form, #form-messages {
    padding: 0 5% 0 5%;
}
form .column {
    width: 100%;
}
form label {
    display: block;
    font-family:"Lato", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #553445;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0 5px 5px 2px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
form input, form textarea {
    display: block;
    font-family:"Lato", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #553445;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(85, 52, 69, 0.1);
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(85, 52, 69, 0.4);
    outline: none;
}
form input:active, form input:focus, form textarea:active, form textarea:focus {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}
form input {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
form textarea {
    min-height: 200px;
    resize: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 30em) {
    #ajax-contact .column {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }
    #ajax-contact textarea {
        min-height: 146px;
    }
    #ajax-contact #bottom-button {
        border-radius: 3px;
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

Do you guys have any idea to put the button on the bottom, yet keep it centered?

Comment: Why are the name and Email fields hovering the textarea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating the button CSS with the following clear property:

```
#ajax-contact #bottom-button {
    clear: both;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Should do the trick as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vtk3oe95/2/).

Comment: To add to your answer: Tip: just don't use inline styles :)

Comment: Good call! Definitely getting late when I make mistakes like that... Thanks.

Comment: Actually your answer was clear, it was just missing the *tip* that it's for simplicity-only > and to use it inside the stylesheet. You won't believe how fresh programmers follow suggestions word-by word :)

Comment: Duly noted. Thanks for the solid response.

Comment: No problem. If you adjust the input width from 100% to 90% it a quick fix for that pesky overlap as well. Your call.

Comment: The overlap only showed in jsfiddle. It looks perfect for me in my site.